# Request to server with $.ajax doesn't return success - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a request to server on a  with jQuery and ajax and process the request with PHP , however , every time the server responds with '404' (in console: Error occurred!) code that I specified in the PHP file.
The problem is that even with the correct username and password , still the request wouldn't return as code 200 (successful).
HTML file is named login.php , JS file is named main-2.js and the file that process the request is login-process.php This is my HTML code :

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#awesome-login-form').submit((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = $('#awesome-login-form').serialize();
    const adminUserName = $('#login-user-name').val();
    const adminPassword = $('#login-password').val();

    $('#usr-err-msg').html('');
    $('#psw-err-msg').html('');
    $('#total-err-msg').html('');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "login-process.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data,
      success: (data) => {
        if (data.code === '200') {
          console.log('It works!');
          window.location.href = 'dashboard-index.php';
        } else if (data.code === '404') {
          console.log('Error occurred!');
          $('#usr-err-msg').innerText = data.nameErrMsg;
          $('#psw-err-msg').innerText = data.passwordErrMsg;
          $('#total-err-msg').innerText = data.totalError;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>IPConcrete | Admin-Login</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login-custom-style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/my-grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my-style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <h2 style="text-align:center;color:#ff5e15;margin-top:50px;">IPCONCRETE</h2>

  <div class="log-form">
    <h2 style="color:#ff5e15;font-weight:800;">Login to your account</h2>


    <form method="post" action="login.php" id="awesome-login-form">
      <input type="text" name="admin_name" title="username" placeholder="username" id="login-user-name" />
      <p id="usr-err-msg" style="display:inline-block;"></p>

      <input type="password" name="admin_password" title="username" placeholder="password" id="login-password" />
      <p id="psw-err-msg" style="display:inline-block;"></p>

      <button type="submit" name="login_btn" class="btn" id="login-submit">Login</button>
      <p id="total-err-msg" style="display:inline-block;"></p>

      <a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot Username?</a>
    </form>


  </div>
  <!--end log form -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main-2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and the PHP file code is:

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
require_once('config.php');



$nameErrMsg = '';
$passwordErrMsg = '';
$totalError = '';
$_SESSION['isAdmin'] = false;

$adminName = $_POST['admin_name'];
$adminPassword = $_POST['admin_password'];
$errorStatus = false;

if (checkEmpty($adminName)) {
   $errorStatus = true;
   $nameErrMsg = 'The user name field is empty!';
}

if (checkEmpty($adminPassword)) {
   $errorStatus = true;
   $passwordErrMsg = 'The password field is empty!';
}

if (!(checkEmpty($adminName)) && !(checkEmpty($adminPassword))) {


   $sqlCommand = "SELECT FROM `io9mp_admins` WHERE `user_name` = ? AND `password` = ?";

   $sqlCommandPrepare = $pdoObject->prepare($sqlCommand);
   $sqlCommandPrepare->execute([

       $adminName,
       $adminPassword

   ]);

   //Checking if the user input values are equal to the data base fields...
   $result = $sqlCommandPrepare->fetch();

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {
       $errorStatus = false;
   } else if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 1) {
       $errorStatus = true;
   }


}


if ($errorStatus === true) {
   echo json_encode([
       'code' => '404', 'totalError' => $totalError, 'nameErrMsg' => $nameErrMsg, 'passwordErrMsg' => $passwordErrMsg
   ], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512);
}

else if ($errorStatus === false) {

   echo json_encode([
       'code' => '200',
   ], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512);
}
```

the checkEmpty() funtion is in functions.php:

```
<?php
function checkEmpty($input){
    return empty( trim($input) );
}
```

Comment: That would mean logically that `mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1` is false

Comment: What PHP version are you using?  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php  *"    Note:

    Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false."*

Comment: @Taplar Currently,my PHP language level is 7.4

Comment: @Taplar In response to your first comment: I took my SQL query to a test file and coded this :$sqlCommand = "SELECT FROM `io9mp_admins` WHERE `user_name` = ? AND `password` = ?";

$sqlCommandPrepare = $pdoObject->prepare($sqlCommand);
 $sqlCommandPrepare->execute([

     'asghar',
     'asghar123'

]);      notice both 'asghar' and 'asghar123' are in my tables and the result is : 'It not works!'

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli? You can't mix them like this.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using PDO.

Comment: Then you can't use `mysqli_XXX` functions to process the results.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much.I will search for alternatives in PDO

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in plain text. You should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `mysqli_XXX` functions when you're using PDO. Change:

```
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {
       $errorStatus = false;
   } else if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 1) {
       $errorStatus = true;
   }
```

to

```
    $errorStatus = !$result;
```

Comment: Thanks! and also I added  * in the sql query command : "SELECT * FROM `io9mp_admins` WHERE `user_name` = ? AND `password` = ?"  to made this code worked